# How to prevent iTunes from launching on media key press

Tags: mac, itunes, music, hotkeys, songbird

Recently, I made the switch to Songbird, and it's all gone well except for one thing: global music hotkeys. I installed an addon ([Apple Keyboard Media Key Support](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1408)) that enabled me to use the iTunes hotkeys for Songbird, but they also open iTunes. How can I prevent iTunes from opening when I press the media keys?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/344803/making-mac-media-keys-open-app-other-than-itunes), which provides a detailed answer using Karabiner (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook).

Comment: @Raim I asked first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MMFix](http://forums.macgeneration.com/mac-os-x/patch-pour-les-touches-play-pause-sous-snow-leopard-300962.html) (english translation [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://forums.macgeneration.com/mac-os-x/patch-pour-les-touches-play-pause-sous-snow-leopard-300962.html)). This tiny little utility patches the remote control daemon, which controls the media keys (and thus freeing it from the grasp of iTunes).

Download link [here](http://nomitsu-kronos.hd.free.fr/download.php?file=mmfix)

Comment: is there a utility that reverses it?

Comment: @tekknolagi running the application again will let you reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook).  It has an option to default the media keys back to F7, F8, and F9, which can then be mapped to your media player of choice.